# Supervisor. Как заставить работать после закрытия консоли?

Tags: python, supervisord

Установил supervisor. Включаю его командой supervisord и все работает - скрипт перезапускается после падения. НО как только я закрываю консоль - все перестает работать.
Может это из за работы в virtualenv?
Как сделать так, чтобы он сам по себе работал?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос: никак. При закрытии терминала автоматически закрываются все задачи, присоединённые к этому терминалу.

Так что есть два варианта:

1. Приложение само должно отсоединиться от терминала. Есть у *Supervisor* ключ запуска в режиме демона?
2. Доверить запуск этой проги самой ОС:

В зависимости от разных дистрибутивов это делается немного по разному, но в любом случае, ищите в настройках нечто вроде "Приложения запускаемые автоматически". Там и пропишите команду запуска.

Если такого не найдёте, тогда придётся оформлять это дело как сервис. Почитайте про *systemd*: https://prudnitskiy.pro/2018/01/24/systemd-quickstart/